# ¿Como puedo hacer que una variable solo acepte un rango mínimo y un maximo de números enteros en c++?

Tags: c++

mi pregunta es la siguiente, yo quiero declarar una variable entera, pero quiero que solo acepte un rango determinado de números, ejemplo:

int variable = número mínimo(1), y el número maximo(50);

Y que por ejemplo la variable tenga 49 y le sume un número como el 8 me de el maximo del rango que yo le pedi, o sea 50, y así mismo con el mínimo.

Todo esto sin usar for, while o algún sistema mucho más complejo.

Answer (score 1):

- Directamente, **no es posible**. Las variables admiten todos los valores que *quepan* en su tamaño. No hay nada que puedas hacer.
- Indirectamente, colocando comparaciones donde sea necesario, puedes ajustar el comportamiento según tus requisitos.

Esto último puede parecer ... tedioso y poco práctico. Salvo por el hecho de que estás en C++, y puedes crear clases y plantillas para que el compilador trabaje **para ti**:

```
#include <iostream>

template< int MIN, int MAX > struct Limited {
    Limited( int val = MIN ) { operator=( val ); }

    Limited &operator=( int newVal ) {
        if( newVal < MIN ) {
            value = MIN;
        } else if( newVal > MAX ) {
            value = MAX;
        } else {
            value = newVal;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    int value;
};

int main( ) {
    Limited< 5, 10 > limited = 1;
    std::cout << "valor: " << limited.value;
    limited = 50;
    std::cout << "\nvalor: " << limited.value;

    return 0;
}
```

Lo anterior muestra:

> valor: 5
> valor: 10

Los valores se han ajustado a tus requisitos; y, sin embargo, el *modo-de-empleo* y todas las comparaciones adicionales están *ocultas* para el *usuario* de la clase, tal y como se observa en el `main( )`:

```
int main( ) {
    Limited< 5, 10 > limited = 1;
    std::cout << "valor: " << limited.value;
    limited = 50;
    std::cout << "\nvalor: " << limited.value;

    return 0;
}
```

En donde no hay ni una sola comparación, y sin embargo los valores se ajustan *automágicamente* a tus requisitos.

<sub>**Nota**: Eso de `algún sistema mucho más complejo` es muy mucho relativo :-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

La solucion mas sencilla es tener un if despues de sumar o restar que compruebe ambas condiciones. Otra solucion es tener un assert que cambie el numero al max o min cuando se necesite